# fetching data from firebase and displaying in django templates (in table format)

Tags: django, django-models, firebase-realtime-database, django-views

hello am new to firebase

I just want to fetch data from firebase and display in django(in table)

**db look like:**
[image]

**code in view.py look like:**

[image]

**code in html look like**

[image]

**o/p look like while running sever**
[image]

please help me out by:  displaying n no of node in templates in table format

Comment: Please post the code as text. Never link screenshots of your code, because we can't use it.

Comment: Hi Baba Ranjit, How are you connecting your django models with firebase? can you please guide me related to this?